# CSS 3 Column Footer Layout (Columns are offset)

Tags: css, css-float, footer, html

So I've written a very simple 3 column footer layout that SHOULD work. But I'm getting different results in different browsers.

The CSS:

```
#footer{
width:980px;
height: 150px;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #94171b;
color: #fff;
}

#footer_left{float:left; width:300px; text-align:left; border: 1px solid;}
#footer_middle{width:300px; text-align:left; border: 1px solid;}
#footer_right{float:right; width:300px; text-align:left; border: 1px solid;}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footer_left">
    <b>SITE NAVIGATION</b><br>
        <a href="/dev/site/">Home</a><br>
        <a href="/dev/site/about.php">About</a><br>
        <a href="/dev/site/dining.php">Food</a><br>
        <a href="/dev/site/drinks.php">Drinks</a><br>
        <a href="/dev/site/">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <div id="footer_middle">
        <b>CONNECT WITH US SOCIALLY</b><br>
        http://www.facebook.com/tbd
        http://www.twitter.com/tbd
        http://www.instagram.com/tbd
        http://www.youtube.com/tbd
      </div>
      <div id="footer_right">
        &copy;2013 Site. All rights reserved<br><br>
        Support Local Business
      </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I get in Chrome:
[image: Chrome Error]

And here's what I get in IE9
[image: IE9 Error]

With as simple as this is, it should work (in theory) but it doesn't. There should be 3 columns of 300px each in a single row. Need a fresh set of eyes at this point. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML solution, is going to always give different results in different browsers.

I fixed up your current HTML and CSS to give a proper 3-column layout. 
I added `float:left` to all elements.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HhCYh/

**Better Solution:**

Personally for my own HTML column layouts, I use this HolyGrail 3 - column layout which works amazing in all browsers even in IE.

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm

Take a look. It requires extra HTML markup in the file but if you want a cross-browser solution in Chrome and IE, this is the best solution.

Good luck
Kiru

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. It worked perfect in Chrome and FF but in IE all the DIVS are stacked. I'll look into the Holy Grail solution and see if it helps.

Comment: I can view the fiddle in IE and it's perfect but when I copy and paste it to replace the code I had, all the divs are stacked on top of each other instead. Any ideas?

Comment: @rsmith84 most likely it has something to do with your existing, surrounding HTML or CSS. Instead of #footer > div, try putting the float:left in each #footerleft, #footermiddle, #footerright?

Comment: That was it! Moving the float declaration to each element fixed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

All your divs have to be floating to do what you're looking for.

Try this, it works well for me on jsfiddle :

```
#footer_left{float:left; width:300px; text-align:left; border: 1px solid;}
#footer_middle{float:left; width:300px; text-align:left; border: 1px solid;}
#footer_right{float:left; width:300px; text-align:left; border: 1px solid;}
```

Considering what you had, Chrome was doing exactly what you asked him to display, while IE9 had your 2nd div in the middle for no reason.